# Use of who clause

Tags: relative-clauses

> It was not Sheldon but David, the poet's friend, who illustrated his new poem, published in the journal.

Can we remove the who? as the parenthesis itself is a who clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't. Reduced relative clauses are applied to relative clauses with

EITHER “**simple present tense**”:

> *... poet's friend, **who illustrates his new book*** => ... poet's friend, **illustrating his new book**

OR “**passive perfect or past**”:

> *... poet's friend's new book, **which was (has been) illustrated recently*** => ... poet's friend's new book, **illustrated recently**

and a few more derivatives of these cases . i.e.: “**passive present continuous**”:

> *... poet's friend's new book, **which is being illustrated*** => ... poet's friend's new book, **being illustrated**

Comment: can you please tell me if verb+inge can always replace that is/who is as your first example suggest. if not, when that is/who must not.

Comment: Well, I'm sorta not sure what your question is. Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: It is not Sheldon but David, the poet's friend, illustrating his new poem, published in the journal. I ask if I can replace "who illustrates" with "illustrating" in all cases.